# Can I do XSL transformation without explicitly provided XSL file?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I am using Transformer to perform XSL transformation from XML to XHTML:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
// ...
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
  .newTransformer(/* xsl */);
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml), new StreamResult(xhtml));
```

In this code I should explicitly provide XSL file. In my situation I don't know which file should be used. Instead, I want the transformer to get this information from `<?xsl-stylesheet?>` processing instruction in the original XML. Is it possible to do with JDK6 and Saxon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xalan can do that, check [this](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html#embed).
Probably Saxon as well as it is method of `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`: `getAssociatedStylesheet`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `@JustYo` suggestion I found it's working well under Saxon.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", 
    "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");

StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslSource = factory.getAssociatedStylesheet(xmlSource, null, null, null);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslSource);
transformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(xhtml));
```